# add & remove event listener with function bound to outer scope

Tags: javascript, frontend, addeventlistener

got a tricky problem. I want to make use of addEventListener and removeEventListener, with a registered non-anonymous function. I don't want to use anonymous functions, because I want to explicitely destroy the event listener I have registered in the first place:

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', myFunction, false);
window.removeEventListener('keyup', myFunction, false);
```

Works like a charm, but here comes the problem:
I'm inside of a class and inside of **myFunction** I'd like to call class members and some class methods, usually bound to *this*, but hey - inside of the addEventListener-method, *this* is bound to *window*. Every attempt, to bind the class-this to the function (e.g. myFunction.bind(this) etc.) was not successfull. So how can I access the class scope?

```
class myClass {
   myMethod(args) {
     console.log('you got them superior coding skillz');
   }

   myCallback(e) {
      var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
      if(key ===  27) {
        this.myMethod(args);
      }
   }

   listeners(addListener) {
      if(addListener === true) {
         window.addEventListener('keyup', this.myCallback, false);
      }
      else {
         window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.myCallback, false);
      }
   }
}
```

Thank you guys for your help! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should looks like this:

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', this.myCallback.bind(this), false)
```

Comment: Already tried this, but it does not work! bind(this), will manipulate the function in a way, the removeEventListener will not recognize it.

Comment: can you add 'console.log(JSON.stringify(this))' inside callback after bind?

Comment: It's not, that bind is not working. It does, giving me the scope of the class, but - removeEventListener won't work, because it won't recognize myCallback as the same function as addEventListener used it.

Comment: but both of them have same scope, you sure in what you said?

Comment: Yeah, because I've tested it many times - and the listener won't be destroyed.